# jquery.jscrollpane issue. Scroll bar not loading

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Building a site in WordPress and its a bit of a weird one.

The site basically uses an advanced drop down menu to display the page content rather than changing pages.

I want to add a (styled) scroll-bar to each of the drop downs to fit all the content in.

I have loaded Jquery Scroll Pane files and I can see its starting to build the divs and styles for the scrollbar but then doesn't actually load the div with the scrollbars in.

You can see it in action [here](http://boutiqueathome.co.uk/wp)

Click the Shopping In Style tab.

The .jspVerticalBar div that is meant to be there....isn't.

I have tried my code on a standard [WordPress page](http://boutiqueathome.co.uk/wp/scroll-test/) and it worked fine.

Can anyone see whats stopping it working on the menu?

Comment: Share some code so people can what's going on

Comment: Are the links to the pages not enough?

Sites using the jquery.scroll plugin which I think is working fine. 

Just not on that homepage for some reason!